# Callback function after file/image is downloaded in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am fetching a JSON file from Reddit and reposting each post with the same title and image on Twitter using the TWIT library. However I have problems whereby the image either do not correspond with the title or the image is half downloaded (looks distorted) and spans across multiple posts:

example:
https://twitter.com/LCHSHITPOST

I am guessing this has to do with the fact that the images are not completely downloaded before the tweet is sent (makeImgTweet function is called).

This snippet gets the json file and then loops through the posts to get the title and image url. It then downloads the image from the url and calls the makeImgTweet function.

```
var url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/teenagers/top.json?t=all";

request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, file) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        // loop through posts in JSON file
        // makes image tweet with title and image url
        (file.data.children).forEach(function(post) {
            var picStream = fs.createWriteStream('image.jpg');
            picStream.on('close', function() {
                console.log('file done');
                makeImgTweet(post.data.title);
            });
            request(post.data.url).pipe(picStream);
        })


    }
})
```

Path of the image is always the same since I do not want to keep them.

makeImgTweet() function:

```
function makeImgTweet(text) {
    var b64content = fs.readFileSync("./image.jpg", { encoding: 'base64' })

    // first we must post the media to Twitter
    Twit.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
        // now we can assign alt text to the media, for use by screen readers and
        // other text-based presentations and interpreters
            if (!err) {

                var mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string;
                var altText = text;
                var meta_params = { media_id: mediaIdStr, alt_text: { text: altText } };

                Twit.post('media/metadata/create', meta_params, function (err, data, response) {
                    if (!err) {
                        // now we can reference the media and post a tweet (media will attach to the tweet)
                        var params = { status: text, media_ids: [mediaIdStr] }

                        Twit.post('statuses/update', params, function (err, data, response) {
                            if (!err) {
                                console.log(data)
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
    })             
}
```